# Problem when downloading ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation

I was trying to install 14.04 on my computer (dual boot).

I am new to Linux and I really don't want to loose my windows OS. Any advise would be appreciated. 
I got this error message "no root file system is defined" [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are doing is creating partitions for your ubuntu installation and not not defining the main / directory
if you are new just click back and as you said you are dual booting with windows just

click install along side windows it will solve the problem
..

but i don't suggest this as you are new 
format that unknown space to ext4
and use it as mount to / and it will remove that error and ubuntu will be installed / is where your ubuntu is installed
and make another partition from that free space and use it as swap just make it as big as your ram ie if your ram is 4gb make it 4gb and swap is virtual memory,
this will work.
but i suggest you to go with upper suggestion